# CSS Table cells width of child table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have nested tables:

```css
#progressHeading thead td.spacingCol {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.collapseProcess {
  background: url(../images/minus.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
}

.expandProcess {
  background: url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
}

#progressHeading {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
}

#progressHeading thead td {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #B8CCE4;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
}

#progressHeading td.startDayCol {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#progressHeading td.endDayCol {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading td.totalDaysCol {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.processCol {
  width: 300px;
}

.startDayCol,
.endDayCol,
.totalDaysCol {
  width: 100px;
}

.statusCol {
  width: 125px
}

table tr td.spacingCol,
table .phaseRow td.spacingCol,
#progressHeading thead td.spacingCol {
  background: #ffffff;
  width: 5px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table tr td:nth-child(9) {
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
}

table tr td:nth-child(5),
table tr td:nth-child(6) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}

table thead td,
table .phaseRow td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#floatDays tbody td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  empty-cells: hide;
}

#progressHeading thead td #calendarDisplay td {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading thead td #dailyDisplay td {
  background-color: #DCE6F1;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading thead td .dailyDisplayRow td {
  height: 12px !important;
}

table td div {
  background-color: #B8CCE4;
  color: #B8CCE4;
}

.dayWidth {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #DCE6F1;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <table id="progressHeading" style="display: table;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="processCol">Process</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="statusCol">Status</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="startDayCol">Start Day</td>
        <td class="endDayCol">End Day</td>
        <td class="totalDaysCol">Total Days</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="calendarCol">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="dailyDisplayRow">
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 05</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 12</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 19</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 26</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 03</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 10</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 17</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 24</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 31</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 07</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 14</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 21</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 28</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 04</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 11</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 18</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 25</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 02</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 09</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 16</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 23</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 30</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 06</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 13</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 20</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 27</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 04</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 11</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 18</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 25</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jan 01</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jan 08</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="dailyDisplayRow" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_ce153c5a_4a3a_4dc9_9b78_f4877028ebbd_dailyDisplay">
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Each of the initial table cells has a set with (`table-layout: fixed`, `width: 100%`) and everything looks great. The problem comes in the last cell. I want to expand the width so that the cell expands to fit the table inside it. Even if I set the `width` with jQuery to the `width` of the contents, it doesn't work.  And if I remove the table layout and `width`, the other cells don't get their respected widths. I don't want to change the `overflow` of the table so you are x-scrolling the width of the table, I want the to keep is so that the horizontal scrolling is on the page. I just want the border of the parent table to extend to the width of the child table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `width: 100%` from table and give `min-width` instead of `width` to each individual `td`.

```css
#progressHeading thead td.spacingCol {
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.collapseProcess {
  background: url(../images/minus.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
}

.expandProcess {
  background: url(../images/plus.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  width: 25px;
}

#progressHeading {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: auto;
}

#progressHeading thead td {
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  background-color: #B8CCE4;
  text-align: center;
  height: 35px;
}

#progressHeading td.startDayCol {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

#progressHeading td.endDayCol {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading td.totalDaysCol {
  border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}

thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.processCol {
  min-width: 300px;
}

.startDayCol,
.endDayCol,
.totalDaysCol {
  min-width: 100px;
}

.statusCol {
  min-width: 125px
}

table tr td.spacingCol,
table .phaseRow td.spacingCol,
#progressHeading thead td.spacingCol {
  background: #ffffff;
  min-width: 5px;
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
  border-top: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #FFFFFF;
}

table tr td:nth-child(9) {
  border-right: 2px solid #000000;
}

table tr td:nth-child(5),
table tr td:nth-child(6) {
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 2px solid #000000;
}

table thead td,
table .phaseRow td {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

#floatDays tbody td {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  empty-cells: hide;
}

#progressHeading thead td #calendarDisplay td {
  width: 100px;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading thead td #dailyDisplay td {
  background-color: #DCE6F1;
  font-weight: normal;
  height: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-right: 1px solid #000000;
}

#progressHeading thead td .dailyDisplayRow td {
  height: 12px !important;
}

table td div {
  background-color: #B8CCE4;
  color: #B8CCE4;
}

.dayWidth {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  color: #000000;
  background-color: #DCE6F1;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <table id="progressHeading" style="display: table;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td class="processCol">Process</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="statusCol">Status</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="startDayCol">Start Day</td>
        <td class="endDayCol">End Day</td>
        <td class="totalDaysCol">Total Days</td>
        <td class="spacingCol"></td>
        <td class="calendarCol">
          <table>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="dailyDisplayRow">
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 05</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 12</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 19</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jun 26</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 03</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 10</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 17</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 24</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jul 31</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 07</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 14</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 21</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Aug 28</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 04</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 11</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 18</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Sep 25</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 02</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 09</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 16</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 23</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Oct 30</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 06</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 13</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 20</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Nov 27</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 04</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 11</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 18</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Dec 25</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jan 01</td>
                <td>Week of <br>Jan 08</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="dailyDisplayRow" id="ctl00_ctl40_g_ce153c5a_4a3a_4dc9_9b78_f4877028ebbd_dailyDisplay">
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="weekClass">
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      M
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      T
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      W
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      Th
                    </div>
                    <div class="dayWidth">
                      F
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="9"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: You can do in other way too, remove width 100% to child and let it be to parent.

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure why this bothered me so much when it is such a simple solution... works great! Thanks!

Removing the width to the child messed up the other cells, that is why I did not do that.  Thanks though!